# How to add hash keys and values to a string

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash,

```
hash = {"a" => 100, "b" => 200, "c" => 300}
```

and would like to add its keys and values to a string.

I have the following code:

```
result_string = ''
hash.each do |key, value|
    result_string += 'key: '
    result_string += key
    result_string += ', value: '
    result_string += value
    result_string += ', '
end
```

The result would be:

```
"key: a, value: 100, key: b, value: 200, key: c, value: 300,"
```

This code does add the current key to the string. However, it doesn't resolve `value` to its value, and I wonder why that is.

Comment: It is not clear what is expected and what is the result of your code.

Comment: If you are debugging, consider `hash.inspect`.  Also for debugging, try `p hash`, which is equivalent to `puts hash.inspect`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an easier way:

```
hash.map { |key, value| "key: #{key}, value: #{value}" }.join(', ')
#=> "key: a, value: 100, key: b, value: 200, key: c, value: 300"
```

Comment: Apparently what I needed was `.map`. Thank you for that!

Answer (score 3):

As to why your code doesn't work - if you try to run it, you will get

> `TypeError`: no implicit conversion of `Fixnum` into `String`

This is because you try to add a number (your values) to a string. To fix it, you can explicitly convert your keys and values to strings. So

```
result_string += key
```

becomes

```
result_string += key.to_s
```

and

```
result_string += value
```

becomes

```
result_string += value.to_s
```

Comment: Adding `.to_s` also helped me solve the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
hash.map(&%w|key:\  value:\ |.method(:zip))
    .map { |e| e.map(&:join).join(', ') }
    .join(', ')
#⇒ "key: a, value: 100, key: b, value: 200, key: c, value: 300"
```

Answering your question: the problem is in `result_string += value`, one can’t just add an integer to the string with `+`, it should be coerced upfront:

```
result_string += value.so_s
```

Comment: Ahah! This might be the least readable code I've ever seen from you!

Comment: @EricDuminil Honestly, I decided to post it here only to honour `&%w|key:\  value:\ |.method(:zip)`.

Answer (score -1):

There are dozens of ways to achieve that. How about this one... Assuming you have a hash then you can traverse through it via [map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html).

```
h = {foo: "bar", batz: "boo"}
h.map { |key, vakue| "key: #{key}, value: #{value}" }
```

in that case produces an array of the strings you're looking for: `["key: foo, value: bar", "key: batz, value: boo"]`